# Nice vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables

How to create nicer vertical lines in the table, please? They should go from the second line to the bottom line without overlapping and spaces.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc}
\hline\hline
A                   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{B}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{C}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{D}    \\
                                   
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} &\multirow{2}{*}{B} &\multirow{2}{*} {C} &\multirow{2}{*}{D} &\multirow{2}{*}{E} &\multirow{2}{*}{F} &\multirow{2}{*}{G} \\
&&&&&&\\[-5pt]

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the only function of `\noalign{\smallskip}` is to force a small space that breaks all the vertical lines simply do not do that if you do not want the space

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question. Now, the problems are the overlaps below and no vertical lines in the first row (between B and C; C and D).

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{B}` removes the lines, `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}` would have a line. (most tables look a lot better without the vertical lines, are you sure you want all these?)

Comment: the overlap at the bottom is again because you have explicitly requested that with `\\[-5pt]` adding negative space will always cause something to overprint something else.

Comment: off-topic: It makes nosense to have both `\centering` and a `center` envrionment. I suggest you get rid of the `center` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem

Comment: @Mico yes dropping the vertical lines [gives that understated refined feel to the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmCm.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for reminding me of the difference between necessary and sufficient conditions for some statement to be true. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear (to me) where you like to have vertical lines. For horizontal lines are available many options:

[image]

With employing the `tabularray` package all tables showed are simple to write. However, beside showing examples, is simple to make other combinations ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines,
             colspec={c|cc|cc|cc},
             }
    \hline
A   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  B 
        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} C 
                &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} D 
                        &       \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
or
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2-Y}=0.2pt,
             colspec={c|cc|cc|cc},
             }
A   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  B
        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} C
                &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} D
                        &       \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
or
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt, hline{3-Y}=0.2pt,
             colspec={c|cc|cc|cc},
             }
A   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  B
        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} C
                &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} D
                        &       \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

or
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt, hline{3-Y}=0.2pt,
             vlines,
             cells={c},
             }
A   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}  B
        &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} C
                &   &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} D
                        &       \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try to wean yourself off using vertical lines in tables. Trust me, the aren't needed, and most tables actually look a whole lot better without them. And, do make use the user macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package -- such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- in place of `\hline` and programming kludges such as `\noalign{\smallskip}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{with vertical lines}\\
\hline\hline
A &\multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{C} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{D} \\                           
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} &\multirow{2}{*}{B} &\multirow{2}{*} {C} &\multirow{2}{*}{D} &\multirow{2}{*}{E} &\multirow{2}{*}{F} &\multirow{2}{*}{G} \\
&&&&&&\\[-5pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{c} @{}}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{without vertical lines}\\
\toprule
A &\multicolumn{2}{c}{B} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{C} &\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{D} \\                           
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
\midrule
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```